# How to configure the user and password for aerospike database in the server

Tags: configuration, passwords, aerospike

I have install a aerospike database in my linux server, and get access to the database by a java client.I have not configured any user and password yet. I want to know how to configure the user and password for the aerospike database in the linux server,then I can get access to the database the using the user and password by the java client.

Answer (score 6):

Security features are only available on the Aerospike Enterprise Edition. If you are using the Enterprise Edition you can find some information [here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/security.html) as well as on each relevant client documentation.

The free Aerospike Community Edition does not support user/password authentication for accessing the database.

Comment: You def should include some "How to secure aerospike community edition" in your docs somewhere